# Cannot access BIOS, Windows loads when F2 pressed

Tags: windows-8.1, bios

I have recently updated an aging XP machine to Windows 8.1. However, when I start it up and try to get the BIOS by pressing F2, it just loads Windows instead. The BIOS was accessible just fine when XP was still installed.

It's an ASRock motherboard with AMI BIOS. At the POST screen, F2 is for BIOS and F11 is for the boot menu. However, pressing any of these just causes Windows to load. I tried pressing the pause/break button to make sure I'm not missing the opportunity to press these buttons, but still Windows loads instead of the BIOS.

Comment: Windows 8 changed how you access the BIOS/UEFI firmware.  You know do so by telling Windows to directly boot to the Advanced Menu and/or having Windows fail to load 3 times.

Comment: @Ramhound Uh, shouldn't the BIOS be checking if the user wishes to enter the configuration before any boot information is even read from any media?

Comment: @Steve BIOS, yes, UEFI - not necessarily. Which does your motherboard have?

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @Ramhound This is an old motherboard so doesn't have UEFI. The old style BIOS is accessed by pressing F2 even in Windows 8 (which I have done before on other Windows 8 computers).

Comment: @BrianFunt - Except you say that isn't working.

Comment: Yes, it's not working for this computer for some reason, even though it says press F2 at the POST screen. I'll try a BIOS reset like mrg2k8's answer when I next get the chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BIOS has nothing to do with the installed OS. You can remove the HDD and still access it.

I remember some in-BIOS options to disable or modify certain key shortcuts used for BIOS access during boot time. If this is the case, a BIOS reset should help (remove BIOS battery, press the power and reset buttons to discharge any capacitors, leave the battery out for half an hour and then put it back).